# Tricky Javascript: how to retrieve value from json dict inside array inside dict :)

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a json file included in my javascript that defines a variable that looks like this:

```
var places_json = {
  "count": 13476,
  "places": [{
      "area": "London",
      "county": "STS",
      "lat": 52.300151820000004,
      "lon": -2.36665606,
      "code": "7567",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "area": "Sheffield",
      "county": "STS",
      "lat": 51.33648680000003,
      "lon": 0.98861179000000001,
      "code": "9919",
      "id": 6
    },
    {
      "area": "Huxton",
      "county": "STS",
      "lat": 53.27483902,
      "lon": -1.0146250700000001,
      "code": "9953",
      "id": 11
    },
  ]
}
```

And I want to retrieve the value of `area` for the entry whose `id` is 11, using Javascript.

Does anyone know how to do this? It's too hard for me - my Javascript is not that advanced. If I knew the array index of the entry that I need, then I could do:

```
var entry = json_places.places[i]
```

but I don't know it, unfortunately, just the value of id (which is unique).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any JS library?

Comment: No - just javascript (though I can add one if it's impossible to do it any other way)

Comment: It's definitely possible, as you can see in the answers below. I was just asking so that I could provide an answer that uses the library instead of generic JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through your places to find the proper item.

```
var area = null;
for(var i = 0; i < json_places.places.length; i++) {
  if(json_places.places[i].id == 11) {
    area = json_places.places[i].area;
    break;
  }
}

alert(area);
```

If you want a function to do it for you, you can run the following:

```
json_places.get_place = function(id) {
   return (function(id) {
             for(var i = 0; i < this.places.length; i++) {
               if(this.places[i].id == id) {
                 return this.places[i];
               }
             }

             return null;
           }).apply(json_places, id);
}
```

Then you can simply do the following:

```
alert(json_places.get_place(11).area);
```

Comment: Use `for in` for hashes, not arrays. It's a bad habit. :)

Comment: @Anthony Mills: There is nothing wrong with using `for in` for arrays. Section `12.6.4` of `ECMA-262` states that any object whose `[[Enumerable]]` attribute is true can be used in such loop. An array qualifies.

Comment: Cheers everyone for all the answers. Picking this one because it worked perfectly first time & for the combination of inline code & function. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew, using `for...in` works, yes, but it's dead slow - http://blogs.sun.com/greimer/resource/loop-test.html - and so is generally accepted as a bad practice.

Comment: @Andrew, also, `for...in` exposes anything added to `Array.prototype` or to the `Array` instance.

Comment: @Andrew Moore Using "for in" on array can give you some surprises. You're not sure of the order of the elements(no more sorting). And then you may loop on some useless custom Array extensions usually provided by some JS libs. Ok, a hasOwnProperty check can avoid it, but then why do all this, when a simple i=0, etc... do the job.

Comment: Crockford suggests using hasOwnProperty, which is fair enough. Not doing that check can cause some sloppy code.

Chances are if you care about clean, maintainable code with prototypical inheritance that you do this already.

Answer (score 3):

```
function findAreaById(placesArray, id) {    
    var place = null;
    for (var i = 0, length = placesArray.length; i < length; i++) {
        place = placesArray[i]; 
        if (place.id === id) {
            return place.area;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_area(places_json, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < places_json.places.length; i++) {
        if (places_json.places[i].id === id) {
            return places_json.places[i].area;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you know you have JavaScript 1.5 available (or you don't mind pasting in the code at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/filter ...), and especially if you know LINQ:

```
function get_area(places_json, id) {
    return places_json.places.filter(function (place) { place.id === id; })[0].area;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (even though this question has been sufficiently answered):

```
var area = null;
$.each(places_json.places, function() {
    if(this.id == 11) {
        alert("Area is " + this.area);
        area = this.area;
        return false;
    }
});
```

See:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/